# В чем ошибка при разбитии массива?

Tags: php, sql

Вот код:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM foto ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4';
      $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
      $out = array_chunk($result, 3);
      foreach($out as $chunk): ?>
        <div id="r_block">
          <?php foreach($chunk as $row): ?>
            <div>
              <a href="<?=$row['name']?>"><?=$row['id']?></a>
            </div>
          <?php endforeach ?>
        </div>
      <?php endforeach ?>
```

Ошибка:

```
Warning: array_chunk() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in C:\Users\scher\Documents\OSPanel\domains\fotoDmitriy\index.php on line 22

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Users\scher\Documents\OSPanel\domains\fotoDmitriy\index.php on line 23
```

Comment: в том что ты разбиваешь не массив

Comment: ААА все забыл fetch_assoc написать спасибо) час бился дурачек

Comment: А не подскажешь статью или пример кода для создания вывода статей, у меня очень криво получается(

Comment: assoc там не при делах, нужен fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)

Comment: если речь о верстке, то и ищи статью про верстку. а потом просто генерируй её на РНР

Comment: ок спасибо) Большое